# How is ELF symbol resolution and relocation different from PE symbol resolution?

Tags: elf, pe, executable

I've learned extensively about PE and PE64 format a while back. I am now digging deeper into ELF format. However, I've not found as many thorough resources for ELF as I did for PE, such as ARTeam's PE format compendium and other blogs. I am looking for a comparison of how dependency/symbol resolution, version symbols, and relocations are done in ELF vs. Portable Executable.

Comment: I think it might be better of you ask some *specific* questions about either format instead of a vague "comparison". Please also check  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Ok I edited the question to be more specific.